# PassportJS with Facebook strategy, is my code correct?

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, passport.js

I use NodeJs with [passportJS](http://passportjs.org/docs/overview) in my app to allow users to login/register using Facebook. It seems to work fine, not sure if I understand fully what is happening there though. So the idea is that users can try to login from different pages in my app using Facebook details. After Facebook returns me all the details I log them in or register new user using what Facebook returned and after this is done redirect them to same page but being already logged in. The code is:

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;


function setupFBStrategy(req, res, next) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        var redirectUrl = req.params.currentPage;

        console.log('setupFBStrategy')
        passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
                clientID: 'abc',
                clientSecret: 'def',
                // step 2 ################################
                callbackURL: "/auth/facebook/callback?currentPage="+redirectUrl,
                passReqToCallback: true,
                profileFields: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'photos', 'email']
                },
                function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
 // step 5 ###########################
// verify callback. Now I have user email inside 'profile' and I authenticate this aginst my database. I use `done(..)` to further instruct my app if the registration/authentication with my system was success or not
                }
        ));
        next();
    }
}

app.use(passport.initialize());

// step 1 ################################
app.get('/auth/facebook/cp/:currentPage', setupFBStrategy(), passport.authenticate('facebook', { authType: 'rerequest', scope: ['email'] }));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.query.currentPage)
         passport.authenticate('facebook', {
            successRedirect: '/'+req.query.currentPage, // redirects when user allowed or logged in with username password
            failureRedirect: '/'+req.query.currentPage // takes here when user clicks cancel when asked to give permissions
        })(req,res,next);
    }
);

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serialize='+user)
    done(null, {});
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('deserialize=' + user);
    done(null, {});
});
```

The steps are:

1. in my app user clicks "login/register with facebook" that makes request to `auth/facebook/cp` route.
2. route calls `setUpFBStrategy`. I append current page user is looking at to callbackUrl.
3. PassportJS send redirect back to user browser and user browser redirects to facebook for authentication.
4. when facebook is finished authenticating user it sends redirect to user browser so the browser redirects to callbackURL with URL specified in step 2. It also appends '`?code=`' querystring to callback URL. Is this querystring  hashed version of what Facebook returns so in my case public info and email?
5. Now my server '`auth/facebook/callback`' is executed and verify callback is executed. Depending if I call `done(null,profile)` etc inside verify callback server returns <del>redirect to browser and browser redirects to `successRedirect` or `failureRedirect`</del> '`successRedirect`' or '`failureRedirect`' routes.

All seems to work so far but is my understanding correct? Is '`code`' querystring hashed version of details facebook returns? Why do I even need `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` functions in my code? When would I use `refreshToken` and `accessToken`?

Answer (score 0):

yes your code seems to be fine.

passport.serializeUser and passport.deserializeUser and function provided by the passport

passport.serializeUser is called once on login when you call

```
req.logIn(someValue,function(){})
```

here someValue is the value you want to store in the passport session

and on every request when you call `req.isAuthenticated()` function to check that the passport session exist or not the passport.deserializeUser will be called returning true or false.
and in end of the user browsing means on logout you call req.session.destroy to destroy that perticular users session.